# text-align: right on <select> or <option>

Tags: html, css, webkit

Does anyone know if it's possible to align text to the right of a `<select>` or more specifically `<option>` element in **WebKit**. This does not need to be a cross-browser solution including IE, but should be pure CSS if it is possible.

I have tried both:

`select { text-align: right }` and `option { text-align: right }`, but neither seems to have worked in WebKit (either Chrome, Safari or Mobile Safari.

Any help gratefully received!

Comment: Somewhere there's a really dumb reason why `option {text-align: right;}` doesn't work.

Answer (score 92, accepted):

You could try using the "dir" attribute, but I'm not sure that would produce the desired effect?

```
<select dir="rtl">
    <option>Foo</option>    
    <option>bar</option>
    <option>to the right</option>
</select>
```

Demo here: http://jsfiddle.net/fparent/YSJU7/

Comment: Actually, that's perfect. I was using the `appearance: none;` attribute anyway, so the position of the dropdown doesn't matter. Thanks!

Comment: This does not work in all cases:     <option>23" x 42"</option>
yields " x 42"23.

rtl also changes how it is read in a screen reader.

Comment: RTL - is the text direction (as example for arabic text) http://jsfiddle.net/iegik/YSJU7/170/

Comment: Doesn't it look like a dirty hack just to give it the proper look without thinking about how it would be processed in some special cases?

Comment: @SergeyBasharov do you have a better solution?

Comment: IMHO this is bad for two reasons. 1. It's semantically wrong. 2. In Chrome 30, `dir="rtl"` moves the arrow indicating the drop-down to the left.

Comment: This is a TERRIBLE idea guys. RTL is meant for languages that draw characters in right-to-left order, and will very much screw up the content that you put in such an option if that content is written in a LTR language. For example a date like "10 Aug 2017" will draw as "Aug 2017 10". You have NO control over what it does to your text. Do NOT use this.

Answer (score 98):

The following CSS will right-align both the arrow and the options:

```css
select { text-align-last: right; }
option { direction: rtl; }
```

```html
<!-- example usage -->
Choose one: <select>
  <option>The first option</option>
  <option>A second, fairly long option</option>
  <option>Last</option>
</select>
```

Comment: Thanks @Laiacy - This is fantastic!  I expect you'll get many more up-votes.

Comment: Thanks to you @pshep123. I really appreciate your comment :)

Comment: This doesn't seem to work for the option values when I click the dropdown (at least on Windows Google Chrome). It only works before the dropdown is toggled.

Comment: @Ryan, I have edited my answer. Now applies to the select and to the option values in the dropdown. Let me know if it works for you

Comment: For me this is the answer. I wanted to keep the small arrow on the right side but the options should be right aligned
=> this is the answer that achieves that

Comment: Perfect!  Thanks.  BOTH arrow and options to the right as desired!

Comment: Perfect solution. Thanks

Comment: **Sadly this does not work.**  `<option>.1</option><option>1</option><option>10</option>` gives right aligned `1.` and `1` and `10` (dot is reversed) http://jsfiddle.net/c2gka8o0/

Comment: I'll upvote this if you remove the `direction: rtl;` bit. That's a hack and definitely should not be used.

Comment: WARNING, `direction: rtl;` is telling CSS this is a right-to-left language (like Hebrew). This  was reversing my text from "11 AM" to "AM 11".

Answer (score 34):

The best solution for me was to make

```
select {
    direction: rtl;
}
```

and then

```
option {
    direction: ltr;
}
```

again. So there is no change in how the text is read in a screen reader or and no formatting-problem.

Comment: Just found out that IE6-8 (don't know about IE8+) don't render that correct… :-/

Comment: And also in Firefox this doesn't work correct. Seems only in Webkit a good idea…

Comment: if your option html contains () that'll move the ) to the beginning of the line (prior to the first character to the left that is). >_<

Comment: Also if you paste "( )" as `&#40;` and `&#41;`?

Comment: I have a drop down list containing values like " 9:30 AM", "10:00 AM", etc..  This was the only solution that worked for me (in Safari 9 on Mac).

Comment: However, on Firefox, the current (selected) value shows with "AM" to the left ("AM 9:30").

Comment: Works in iOS 9 Mobile Safari. Great!!

Comment: although this one make all to the right and option in left, but in my case it will make the arrow position in left side.

Answer (score 25):

I think what you want is:

```
select {
  direction: rtl;
}
```

fiddled here: http://jsfiddle.net/neilheinrich/XS3yQ/

Comment: Cool, but the arrow then goes left. What if we want both text and selection arrow to be aligned to right ?

Answer (score 1):

I was facing the same issue in which I need to align selected placeholder value to the right of the select box & also need to align options to right but when I have used  direction: rtl; to select & applied some right padding to select then all options also getting shift to the right by padding as I only want to apply padding to selected placeholder.

I have fixed the issue by the following the style:

```
select:first-child{
  text-indent: 24%;
  direction: rtl;
  padding-right: 7px;
}

select option{
  direction: rtl;
}
```

You can change text-indent as per your requirement.  Hope it will help you.