# Safari browser: set <option> text align in <select> tag right

Tags: html, css, safari

How can I set text direction of select option tag Right?

```
<select style="direction:rtl;text-align:right">
    <option value="" selected="">همه</option>
    <option value="1">راهبر سيستم</option>
    <option value="0">عادی</option>
</select>
```

[image: safari vs other browsers]

jsfiddle:
http://jsfiddle.net/CHg8v/

Solutions in duplicated question does not cover my problem:

[`text-align: right on <select> or <option>`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7920677/text-align-right-on-select-or-option)

UPDATE:I am using safari 5.1 in windows.

`text-align:-webkit-right` does not works in safari 5.1 for windows

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Safari having the issue(bug) with the `<Select>`option for the `text-align:right` with the `direction:rtl` property. Please check following link for bug report:--

-->https://bugs.webkit.org/show_bug.cgi?format=multiple&id=19785

beside that I also find so many forums which reported this issue check some of then :--

-->http://csscreator.com/node/32981

-->http://css-tricks.com/forums/topic/aligning-select-box-options-to-the-right-in-safari/

-->http://hintsforums.macworld.com/showthread.php?t=107502

You can be do google for more information about this bug,

In the safari road maps(Implementations) I didn't hear any solution for this bug/issue.

Comment: did you seen my attached image, Did I test it as your specified browser and platform??

Comment: postimg.org does not service to Iranian users. I cant see your image. It does not works in Safari for windows

Comment: yeah I tested it with the Windows platform on the Safari 5.1 as you listed in your question.

Comment: Please give a try with this 'text-align:-webkit-right; text-indent:-.5em;'

Comment: I also search some forums and I think this is the bug with the safari, it doesn't support text align with right direction property in the Select tag,
But the surprising thing is that the Chrome and Safari renders same type of webkit environment, But it is perfectly works in Chrome but didn't in safari.

Comment: If you have website as source of this bug, please update your answer with it, So I mark your answer as best answer

Comment: See the Updated answer with the bug report

Answer (score 0):

use this: .classNameOfYourSelect input[type=option]{styling you want to add here}.
By this way you edit only the Option elements with the specific css you will write inside the brackets, like color, background color and whatever you want.

Comment: This is not my answer!

Comment: if you want to simply move the arrow from the default right position to left make your select element look like this <select dir="rtl">. I tried it on Safari and it looks the same way on chrome,mozilla and ie.

Comment: I need to change text align

Comment: I understood what you want. You want to reverse the text orientation, not direction. From right to left as for the arabic languages. give your select box class/id, then from the css do this: #selectBox >option{  unicode-bidi:bidi-override;
  direction:rtl;}

Answer (score 0):

try out this
`text-align:-webkit-right`