# Align SELECT-OPTIONS text to right

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, html

These are the screen shots of the form I am developing.

[image]

[image]

I want to design select box in form in such a way that text in options is right aligned and after selecting the option it selected text shown also should be displayed as shown in below image.

[image]

HTML Code:

```
<select>
    <option value="0" selected="selected" style="text-align: right;">EqualsTo</option>
    <option value="1">LessThan</option>
    <option value="2">GreaterThan</option>
    <option value="3">LessThanEqualsTo</option>
    <option value="4">GreaterThanEqualsTo</option>
    <option value="5">Between</option>
</select>
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [text-align: right on <select> or <option>](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7920677/text-align-right-on-select-or-option)

Comment: I want arrow of select option on the right side only

Comment: AFAIK it can't be done in CSS alone. One of the many properties of `select` elements that can't be customized.

Comment: ohk..Can you suggest any workaround then?

Comment: Sure, you could use other HTML elements with JavaScript to mirror the functionality of a select box. Or, just use a library like [jQuery](http://jquery.com/) with a [plugin](http://gregfranko.com/jquery.selectBoxIt.js/). A little overkill though, just to get a select box to align some text differently. Personally I'd just accept the left aligned text and be done with it.

Comment: Please mention how you are options to dropdownlist!

Comment: sure @oGeez..can you remove your vote to close this question?

Comment: @Ajinkya   see my demo in my answer

Comment: @Ajinkya  see my demo

Comment: @oGeez: After trying hard I could do it just with CSS alone.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Try this.

http://jsfiddle.net/MfDTU/1/

HTML

```
<select id="mySelect" dir="rtl">
    <option value="0" selected="selected" >EqualsTo</option>
    <option value="1">LessThan</option>
    <option value="2">GreaterThan</option>
    <option value="3">LessThanEqualsTo</option>
    <option value="4">GreaterThanEqualsTo</option>
    <option value="5">Between</option>
</select>
```

JS

```
function InitializeSelect(elem) {
    $("#" + elem).each(function () {
        $(this).wrap('<div class="selectbox"/>');
        $(this).after("<span class='selecttext'></span><span class='select-arrow'></span>");
        var val = $(this).children("option:selected").text();
        $(this).next(".selecttext").text(val);
        $(this).change(function () {
           var val = $(this).children("option:selected").text();
           $(this).next(".selecttext").text(val);
       });
       var selectId = $(this).attr('id');
          if (selectId !== undefined) {
           var linkClass = selectId;
       }
       if (linkClass) {
           $(this).parent('.selectbox').addClass(linkClass);
       }
   });
}

$(document).ready(function(){
    InitializeSelect('mySelect');
});
```

CSS

```
.selectbox {
position: relative;
display: inline-block;
*display: inline;
zoom: 1;
border: 1px solid #CCC;
background: none repeat scroll 0 0 #FFFFFF;
min-width: 160px;
max-width:220px;
width: auto;
```

}

```
.selectbox select {
z-index: 10;
position: relative;
border: none;
background: none;
outline: none;
opacity: 0;
height: 27px;
-webkit-appearance: none;
filter: alpha(opacity=0);
width: 100%;
cursor: pointer;
```

}

```
.selectbox select option {
padding: 3px;
text-align:right;
```

}

```
.selecttext {
z-index: 9;
position: absolute;
right: 25px;
display: inline-block;
*display: inline;
zoom: 1;
padding-top: 4px;
background: transparent;
color: #000;
text-align:right;
```

}

```
.select-arrow {
background: url(myarrow.png) no-repeat 50% 50%;
position: absolute;
display: inline-block;
*display: inline;
zoom: 1;
height: 100%;
width: 24px;
top: 0;
right: 0;
}
```

Comment: Holy jumpin'! That is some dedication.

Answer (score 7):

Try this CSS:

```
select{
   direction: rtl;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can try this to keep the arrow of the select option on the right side:

```
select {
    text-align-last: right;
}

option {
    direction: rtl;
}
```

Comment: This doesn't seem to work for the option values when I click the dropdown (at least on Windows Google Chrome). It only works before the dropdown is toggled.

Comment: @Ryan, I have edited my answer. Now applies to the select and to the option values in the dropdown. Let me know if it works for you

Answer (score 1):

Try this : **Demo** http://jsfiddle.net/4RSGu/2/

```
  <select dir="rtl">
    <option value="0" selected="selected" style="text-align: right;" dir="rtl">EqualsTo</option>
    <option value="1" dir="rtl">LessThan</option>
    <option value="2" dir="rtl">GreaterThan</option>
    <option value="3" dir="rtl">LessThanEqualsTo</option>
    <option value="4" dir="rtl">GreaterThanEqualsTo</option>
    <option value="5" dir="rtl">Between</option>
</select>
```

Comment: Now Check it in chrome @Ajinkya

Comment: as I said in one of my comment I wanted arrow to right only..thanks

Answer (score 0):

```
<select style="text-align-last: right;">
    <option value="0" dir="rtl" selected="selected">EqualsTo</option>
    <option value="1" dir="rtl">LessThan</option>
    <option value="2" dir="rtl">GreaterThan</option>
    <option value="3" dir="rtl">LessThanEqualsTo</option>
    <option value="4" dir="rtl">GreaterThanEqualsTo</option>
    <option value="5" dir="rtl">Between</option>
</select>
```

Answer (score -3):

I could do it just with CSS alone.

```
select {
    width: auto;
    -webkit-appearance: none;
    -moz-appearance: none;
    padding: 2px 2px 2px 2px;
    border: none;
    background: transparent url(../images/dropdown.png) no-repeat 161px center;
    background-position-x: 98%;
}

select::-ms-expand {
    display: none;
}
```

This is fiddle for it: http://jsfiddle.net/ajinkya34/nc548/

Comment: the `dir` attribute is not CSS, it's HTML and it should be the only thing specified in your answer. @ajinkya

Comment: In your posted fiddle, if you remove only the HTML attr `dir="rtl"` from the select element, the alignment goes back to normal (left aligned). As `softcode` pointed out above, the CSS you posted does nothing. Sorry, but -1.

Comment: @Eiko: This solution worked for me. Can you tell me which one I should accept as an answer then?