# Align text of <select> <option> to the right

Tags: html, forms, css

Surprisingly in

```
<select>
   <option>Text</option>
</select>
```

---

```
option {
    text-align: right;
}
```

does not work, and I am in search of a solution to achieve this. I understand this is small question, but I can't figure out why it is not working

Comment: Simple - it is still impossible to style option tag with CSS only: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7208786/how-to-style-the-option-of-a-html-select

Comment: DUPLICATE
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24448122/align-select-options-text-to-right

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try with `direction` attribute and use the direction right to left i.e. `rtl`

```
<select dir="rtl">
    <option>Text</option>
</select>
```

[Js Fiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/f39v7fyp/)

Update : if you want to keep arrow icon to right with options to be aligned `right` then you can just set the property on `option` instead of `select`

```
option{
    direction:rtl;
}
```

[Js Fiddle Demo 2](http://jsfiddle.net/f39v7fyp/1/)

Comment: Works, although it also moves select button to the opposite (left) side, where as I'd like just text aligned to it.

Comment: @Ilja. I have updated the post. Please take a look and let me know if it works for you

Comment: Not quiet, it aligns option list to the right when it is expanded, but what I am trying to achieve here is move just text to the right so in an updated example http://jsfiddle.net/f39v7fyp/3/ See how there is a lot of whitespace on the right from the text? I want this whitespace to occur on the left.