# Select element's text-align not working in IE

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer

I have been working and testing with a select element.
I want to align the text to the right. On Chrome and Firefox it's working perfectly...however with dear old IE it doesn't seem to work.

Here is my code:

```css
#inputGroupSelect05 {
    width: 100%;
    background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0) url("../img/chevron-bottom-white-2x.png") no-repeat left .75rem center;
    text-align: right;
    -ms-text-align: right;
    text-align-last: right;
    -ms-text-align-last: right;
}

select#inputGroupSelect05 {
    width: 100%;
    text-align: right;
    -ms-text-align: right;
    text-align-last: right;
    -ms-text-align-last: right;
}

select#inputGroupSelect05 > option {
    background-color: white;
    color: black;
    width: 100%;
    text-align: right;
    -ms-text-align: right;
    text-align-last: right;
    -ms-text-align-last: right;
}
```

```html
<div class="col-sm-6 col-md-3 col-lg-3">
  <select class="custom-select" id="inputGroupSelect05" style="color: white;">
    <option selected>More Search Options</option>
    <option value="1">One</option>
    <option value="2">Two</option>
    <option value="3">Three</option>
  </select>
</div>
```

As you can see in the CSS I included the -ms- prefix aswell, but still the problem persists in IE.
I am stumped with this dilemma, please help.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [text-align: right on <select> or <option>](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7920677/text-align-right-on-select-or-option)

Comment: dear old IE should rest in peace

Comment: Have you found a solution?

Answer (score 1):

Try to add `dir="rtl"`.
This works for me in IE.

Have a look at this [SO-Post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7920677/text-align-right-on-select-or-option).

```css
select, option {
    text-align:right;   
}

option {
  direction:rtl;
}
```

```html
<select>
    <option>Foo</option>    
    <option>bar</option>
    <option>to the right</option>
</select>

<select dir="rtl">
    <option>Foo</option>    
    <option>bar</option>
    <option>to the right</option>
</select>
```